# need a regex to separate this

Tags: regex

I want change this :

```
NetworkAdmin:500:BCCC8D13C24BB4CFECB8865227C3F566:::
```

to this:

```
NetworkAdmin:BCCC8D13C24BB4CFECB8865227C3F566
```

??

Comment: Will 500 always be 500? Could 500 have more than 3 numerals? Will `NetworkAdmin` always be `NetworkAdmin`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to match:

```
([^:]+:)\d+:+([^:]+):*
```

And replace with `$1$2`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bW4hA5/4)

Comment: thank you but dear but what i will do if i have a list with manyyyyy of this ?

Code:

NetworkAdmin:500:BCCC8D13C24BB4CFECB8865227C3F566:::
Admin:50::BCCC8D13C24BB4CFECB8865227C3F566:::
AUser1:10:BCCC8D13C24BB4CFECB8865227C3F566::

....etc

any solution for this?
final transformation will be this:

NetworkAdmin:BCCC8D13C24BB4CFECB8865227C3F566
Admin:BCCC8D13C24BB4CFECB8865227C3F566
AUser1:BCCC8D13C24BB4CFECB8865227C3F566